# FreeRTOS Semaphore overhead time

Tags: embedded, semaphore, rtos, freertos

First of all I would like to note that I am quite new at the RTOS business.

I am using FreeRTOS on my STM32L151VC arm processor. 
I am using binary-semaphore to sync between an interrupt and some task (The semaphore state that the DMA has finished its action). Now, The time passed between the command of xSemaphoreGiveFromISR() to the required task being on and running again is about 50[us]. That seems too long to me, isn't it?

I would like to state, that for this test I have used only 1 task (and IDLE task), my cpu clk is 24[MHz]. I have looked on FreeRTOS and StackOverflow web-sites for some answer and didn't find any.
I only found a statement that this action should take less then 1[us].

My question is, has anyone encountered a similar problem?
Anyone knows how to solve this time overhead problem?

Thanks for all the helpers..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have `configUSE_PORT_OPTIMISED_TASK_SELECTION` set to `1` in FreeRTOSConfig.h?  If so then task selection will be performed using a CLZ instruction, rather than a generic C algorithm, and hence be *much* faster.

After giving the semaphore, do you call `portEND_SWITCHING_ISR( x )`, where `x` is the value passed out of the semaphore give function?  If so then your task switch will happen immediately rather than waiting until the next tick interrupt.

By the way - for best results - ask FreeRTOS support questions on the FreeRTOS support forum as that is where people who use FreeRTOS every day will be able to give you expert advice

http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/freertos_support_forum_archive_index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have previously evaluated FreeRTOS on STM32, in my case running at 72MHz using ARM's RealView compiler, and measured context switch times in the order of 15us in a compiler-optimised build.  This compared with 5us for Keil RTX and 10us for Segger embOS.

The fact that your clock rate is lower and your tool-chain may be different, and you may or may not have applied optimisation (to at least the FreeRTOS library), I would suggest that 50us is entirely plausible.  At 1.2MIPS/MHz achievable by Cortex-M3, that amounts to about 1440 instructions, but it is not clear how you are measuring this time and what overhead that may carry.

The time between the interrupt and the entry to the interrupt handler will be fast - Cortex-M3 can run C code ISRs directly with no glue code.  That is probably what the <1us refers to.

You might improve the time marginally by disabling WFI in the idle loop (at the expense of higher power consumption), and you should ensure that the FreeRTOS library is compiled with optimisation.

If you don't need a counting object, you might try using [event flags](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Event-Groups.html#event_bits) rather than a semaphore - these are likely to have lower overhead.

Comment: Hi Clifford. First, thank you for the prompt answer. But I  don't get it... That means that I want to use Semaphores for message transfer, the maximum rate possible is 1/50[us] = 20k. Isn't it to slow?

Comment: BTW, I am using IAR, with medium optimization.

Comment: The measurement is done with Oscilloscope, by manipulating GPIO when the xSemaphoreGiveFromISR() command is issued and when the xSemaphoreTake() is issued.

Comment: If you just wanted a volatile flag between an ISR and a main program loop it would be quite fast; likely it's the weight of task switching (and possibly the scheduler too) of the RTOS slowing you down.  If you are going to stick with the RTOS, can you use larger buffers to move data with fewer context switches?

Comment: @user3239557 : There is not much to get, the performance of FreeRTOS is what it is, largely due to its implementation. Consider using event flags rather than a semaphore (updated answer).

Comment: Hi, I have tried using event flags. This feature has even larger overhead. From What I have seen, this because there is a non-deterministic calculation from ISR (when using xEventGroupSetBitsFromISR()). That is why I decided to go with binary-semaphore.

Comment: @user3239557 : Are you sure?  If it is non-deterministic, it hardly qualifies as an RTOS.  Deterministic is not the same as *fast*.  As I said, I already rejected FreeRTOS on performance, and the performance you have observed looks comparable to my experience given your low-end Cortex-M target.  In most traditional RTOS the fundamental primitive that enables all other services is the mutex, but in FreeRTOS it is the queue, which seems an odd design decision to me, and is probably a factor in its performance.